# Why Red Cross over the Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on java project with Eclipse.There is no Error in the java files but still there is a Red Cross over the Project.

Please how can I resolve the issue..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post the complete error message, eclipse shows in markers panels

Comment: There is certainly an error in your project somewhere. It doesn't have to be in a Java file. It could be an XML file where you have an open tag without the corresponding close tag. Saying *Please resolve the issue* sounds like a joke. If you aren't joking, delete your question because it's bad for your karma.

Comment: There may be some error somewhere. Maybe problem with dependencies. Check it in dependencies

Comment: Look in the Problems view

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for issues in the 'Problems' view of Eclipse. To open the 'Problems' view, you can use the 'Show View' item under the 'Window' top menu. The 'Problems' view would show you all errors related to your current project(s). 
First, you need to identify the issues (using this view) and then decide how and whether to resolve them ( you may have issues in your JS/XML etc files which may not actually impact running your project).

Comment: That was a issue in the JSP and that was the reason for red cross..

Answer (score 0):

What the error has been shown in problem view.
check the build path or other dependency in project properties.